# this is giving error.plz suggest some answer

Tags: android

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
//                Log.d("imageId--- ", String.valueOf(dataModel.getImageid()));
//
//                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
//                intent.putExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_DRAWABLE_ID, dataModel.getImageid());
//                intent.putExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_NAME, dataModel.getName());
//                intent.putExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_COST, dataModel.getPrice());
//                intent.putExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_NAME_DETAIL, dataModel.getDetailName());
//                intent.putExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_DETAIL, dataModel.getDetail());


                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("keyclassobject",dataModel);


                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

another activity is
 final DataModel dataModel = (DataModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("keyclass");
//         drawableId = intent.getIntExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_DRAWABLE_ID, 0);
//        String itemName = intent.getStringExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_NAME);
//        String itemCost = intent.getStringExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_COST);
//        String itemNameDetail = intent.getStringExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_NAME_DETAIL);
//        String itemDetail = intent.getStringExtra(IntentKeyConstant.INTENT_KEY_ITEM_DETAIL);
        //Log.d("name", itemName);
        // Log.d("itemcost",itemCost);
        //Log.d("imageId ",String.valueOf(drawableId)+ "-"+Integer.parseInt(drawableId));
        Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
        tv_item_rupee_symbol=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_item_rupee_symbol);
        tv_item_rupee_symbol.setTypeface(typeface);


        toolbar_title.setText(dataModel.getName());


        iv_item.setImageResource(dataModel.getImageid());
        tv_item_name_detail.setText(dataModel.getDetailName());
        tv_item_rupee_symbol.setText("\uf156");
        tv_item_cost.setText(dataModel.getPrice());
        tv_item_detail.setText(dataModel.getDetail());
```

Comment: As Rotwang said, clean up this post! Secondly, StackOverflow is not a community where you can say `This doesn't work. Fix it for me`. Do research and **try** to fix the error yourself before asking

Comment: actually what is the issue?

Comment: don't you have head and tail for this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

If your extra data is represented as strings, then you can use `intent.getStringExtra(String name)` method. In your case:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("keyclassobject");
```